# Is there a way to test for sig difference across 10 sample points

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have various elemental concentrations (Barium, Zinc, etc.) across 10 sample points in one lake. I want to know if I have significant differences in certain elements in certain sample points.
Is there a way to test if certain sample points (ID) have a significant difference by each element?
Data example:

```
     Barium, Magnesium, Zinc, etc. 
ID1    1       1         0
ID2    1.1     2         0
ID3    2       1.5       0.1
ID4    1.7     1.6       6
ID5    5       1.7       2
etc.
```

Comment: Can you clarify by example what you mean by an interesting or important difference? For example, Is ID5 remarkable because it has more zinc than the others?

Comment: If you are looking for a significance test, you first need to formulate a null and an alternative hypothesis. Please do so.

Comment: Hi @BruceET , this is an example of possible data but yes I would assume that if this was real ID5 would be sig diff than  ID1-4 FOR Barium and ID4 would be sig diff than ID1-3, 5 for Zinc. Roland my null/alternate hypothesis would be for each element for example "Null: Barium is the same across all 10 locations" "Alternate Barium is not the same across all 10 locations" and if so which locations are not the same (significantly different than the majority). I would do this for each element across the 10 points.

Comment: @Roland /\ please see comment above

Comment: I believe you could use outlier tests. You can probably safely assume a normal distribution for concentration measurements (but you need to judge that based on your domain knowledge). However, you have small sample sizes and Grubbs's test or Dixon's Q test have a different alternative than you formulated.